# Is it somehow possible to use current nightly builds of SUMO in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to use Veins with functionality that was only recently added to SUMO and that is still being further developed. The work that I have in mind is a PhD project that has recently started, and I suppose the simulation part will not start before 2021. Given that Veins currently uses SUMO version 1.2.0, and that, IIRC, the TraCI protocol has been updated after that, how difficult would it be for us to update the system so that Veins works with SUMO 1.4.x or even better with the future 1.5.x? Which skills would be needed?

Comment: To get an impression of how complicated it is to add (simple) commands to the TraCI API, you can compare https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc#L134 and https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v1_3_1/src/traci-server/TraCIServerAPI_Vehicle.cpp#L734 - this is the code for the Veins and the SUMO counterparts of how to change a vehicle’s speed mode.

Answer (score 1):

The current Veins master works with Sumo 1.3.1 already. Afaik, neither version 1.4.0 nor the current progress on Sumo's master branch have been tested, but looking at the changelogs, it seems that there were no changes that look like they should break the current implementation, as mostly new functions have been added that are not yet implemented in Veins. I'd suggest simply running the Veins example against a Sumo-master, if this works without issues that's a good indicator that also more sophisticated simulations will work.